# How to make cucumber run all feature if no matching tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, spork

Im using cucumber with fork. I really like the run_all_when_everything_filtered on Rspec. that runs all the spec if there is no matching tag. Can I do this with cucumber. example in my auto test profile, i specify --tags @wip, but if there is no matching tags it run all of the scenario

Comment: Can you clarify - you want to be able to specify a tag such as `@wip`, and have it run those scenarios tagged as such, but if it happens that _no scenario in your whole suite_ has a `@wip` tag, then it will instead run everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Cucumber doesn't support this natively.  If you're using Guard to run these, you could probably get the behaviour you're after by calling out to a script or custom rake task instead of invoking Cucumber directly.

It should be fairly trivial to write a script or rake task to invoke Cucumber with the `-t @wip` argument, then check to see if the output contains '0 scenarios', and if so then run Cucumber again without a `-t` argument, to execute the whole suite.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the tag, you can specify the tag with an "~" before the tag. That is  `--tags ~@wip`.

What this means, is the tag you specify to cucumber, can be a boolean expression.

- The "~" option before the tag, represents a `NOT`.
- You can specify an `OR`, if you write `--tags @wip1,@wip2`.
- You can specify an `AND`, by writing the --tags options several times.

I encourage you to run `cucumber -h` and checkout the option --tags, to see more information.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with the tags option, but i use guard so basically it's specify in cucumber.yml. but switching to use tag means that i have to edit it manually. that's is what im doing now, rspec have this functionality when a 'tag' is specified, but there is no tag, it run all of the spec (like it's ignoring the tag). I wonder if cucumber have this feature.